# How to access hashmap values from another class?

Tags: java, android, collections, hashmap

I would like to access hashmap set of values created in main class from other class.I have followed the steps for it but I am only getting null value at the sub-class.Here is the code

```
public class SoapTester extends Activity {  
private static final String TAG = "Test";  
public HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    map.put("year", "Apple");
    map.put("make", "Mango");
    map.put("model", "Grape");
    map.put("style", "Orange");
    map.put("series", "Peach");
}

public HashMap<String, String> getHashmap() {
    Log.v(TAG, "map2: E" + map);
    return map;
}

public void setHashmap(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    this.map = map;
    getHashmap();
    Log.v(TAG, "map1: E" + map);
}
}
```

//Sub Class

```
public class Tradein extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Test";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tradein);
    SoapTester ex = new SoapTester();
    HashMap<String, String> hm = ex.getHashmap();
    Log.v(TAG, "hm: " + hm);//Getting Null Value here
}
}
```

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Which error are you getting exactly and in which line?

Comment: Is this really all what you are showing us? I'd think `ex.test` would not compile?

Comment: I have edited the place where I get the null value above...

Comment: Interesting. I thought the `hm` would be an empty HashMap.

Comment: @HeikoRupp I get it I made typo,I have pointed out the exact place above,kindly help if you can.

Comment: @user802421 I am not getting what you are about to tell

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @Vanathi's answer if the `hm` is not null (initialized member variable).

Comment: @user802421 when I print the HashMap I get the output in Main Class but not in sub class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

make the  HashMap static

```
public static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

In this way we can change values in any activity at will, regardless of the exact flow of control between the various activities.

Note that this trick can only be used if you don't care about the instantiation of more than one copy of the same activity (class) in the application, this is the easiest to implement

Step 2 : [Android; Implementing global state; share data between Activities and across your application](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-implementing-global-state-share-data-between-activities-and-across-your-application/)

Comment: According to the link I provided this post (and the others below) is misleading. Consider modifying them.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a try.

I don`t know anything about andriod implementation. But here is my try.

```
SoapTester ex = new SoapTester();
ex.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
HashMap<String, String> hm = ex.getHashmap();
Log.v(TAG, "hm: " + hm);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); is a mandatory statement in android execution.

Comment: oh, ok. So when you do `SoapTester ex = new SoapTester();`, onCreate will be called? like that?

Comment: @Vanathi No, it will not be called. `onCreate` is a callback from the Android system.

Answer (score 1):

use **this.getHashmap()** instead of ex.getHashmap()

```
public class Tradein extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Test";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tradein);
    //SoapTester ex = new SoapTester();
    HashMap<String, String> hm = this.getHashmap();
    Log.v(TAG, "hm: " + hm);//Getting Null Value here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill in the map directly in the class initialization:

```
public class SoapTester extends Activity {  
private static final String TAG = "Test";  
public static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("year", "Apple");
        put("make", "Mango");
        put("model", "Grape");
        put("style", "Orange");
        put("series", "Peach");
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // No map initialization here
    }

// etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple to pass Hashmap as argument, You just need to initialize it in the Parent class's constructor.

Child Class:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();;
    map.put("OS", "Android");
Parent parent= new Parent();
parent.hashtest(map);
```

Parent Class:

```
public class parent{
HashMap<String, String> map;
public Test() {
    map= new HashMap<>();
}

public void hashtest(HashMap<String, String> map){
    this.map=map;
    Log.v("I fount it here", map.get("OS"));
}
}
```